# How to make game character (user) move smooth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

in my game i have set my character to move. How it is set is:

```
if game_over_state == False:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pause = True
            game_paused()
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player_x_change = -2
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player_x_change = 2
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player_y_change = -2
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_y_change = 2

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT
            player_x_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            player_y_change = 0
```

Is it a way to change this to a while function or something so the character doesn't stop moving when release a arrow-key (even though another arrow-key is held down)?

Comment: How it works now is that if you hold the right arrowkey and the down arrowkey and release one of them, then the player would stop completely - even though the other key is held down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is the condition in `event.type == pygame.KEYUP`.

> ```
> if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
>    # [...]    
>
>    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
>         player_y_change = 0
> ```

Just reset either `player_x_change` or `player_y_change`, dependent on the key that is released:

```py
if game_over_state == False:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pause = True
            game_paused()
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player_x_change = -2
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player_x_change = 2
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player_y_change = -2
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_y_change = 2

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT
            player_x_change = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_y_change = 0
```

---

If you want to handle the keys simultaneously, that means you want to move the player diagonal when 2 keys are pressed and you don't want to that the player stops, when 1 key is released, then I recommend to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) rather than the `KEYDOWN` event:

```py
for event in  in pygame.event.get():
    if game_over_state == False:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pause = True
                game_paused()

if game_over_state == False:

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player_x_change, player_y_change = 0, 0
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player_x_change -= 2
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player_x_change += 2
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player_y_change -= 2
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player_y_change += 2
```

Comment: I might have formulated the question poorly, but that would make the player continously float in the direction of the pressed key until another key is pressed and float in that direction - never being able to stop moving. Ist there a way to do like 
        while event.key == pygame.K_LEFT
             player_y_change = -2  

I tried something like this, but it froze the whole program
@Rabbid76

Comment: @Mokoisa Yes of course, I thought that is what you want. You asked *"[...] so the character doesn't stop moving when release a arrow-key [...]"*. Either the charater stops when the key is released or it does not stop. I can't see any other possibility.

Comment: my bad for the poor formulated question.

what i ment was how to move for example up and down, releasing the right key, stop moving to the right but continue to move up.  how it is now it stops in both directions.     

But nevermind   i found the problem by looking at what you had commented out on your first reply. the up and down is just wrong -  

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT
            player_x_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            player_y_change = 0

 thanks  anyways :)

Comment: @Mokoisa I've changed the answer. I provided 2 solutions, both should work for you.